# How to Inject plumbing code in the methods and properties of a .NET class?

Tags: .net, aop, code-injection

A part of implementing the IDisposable pattern in .NET is to check if the object is disposed in all the methods/properies like so:

```
void SomeMethod()
{
    if (Disposed)
        throw new ObjectDisposedException("Object already disposed", (Exception)null);
    ...
}
```

Instead of cluttering the code with this kind of plumbing code I would like a light-weight tool that can inject it in a post-build step for all the classes that implements the IDisposable pattern. Any recommendations?

Comment: why bother with the `(Exception)null` bit in the example above?

Comment: @Sam: have to explicitly specify which of the overloaded constructors to use, otherwise the compiler complains about ambiguity since there's another constructor taking two string arguments.

Answer (score 5):

Do not write code like this in your Dispose() method.  It is not a logical error to dispose an object more than once.  It in fact very commonly happens, a FileStream passed to a StreamReader is a classical example.

```
        using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)) {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
                // etc..
            }
        }
```

The *fs* object is disposed twice here.  Avoiding this just causes trouble if there are any exceptions.

---

In case you are not actually talking about "implementing the Dispose pattern" like your question says but just want to check in any methods whether the object was disposed: keep it KISS:

```
private bool CheckDisposed() {
    if (this.disposed) throw new ObjectDisposedException();
}
```

Or just write it inline.  Adding any verbiage to the exception message is unnecessary.  The exception is crystal clear and means only one thing.  And is of course the kind of exception that should only ever strike in debug sessions and unit tests.  Throwing the AOP weapon at it isn't impossible but perhaps a bit heavy-handed.  Very hard to get ahead when an attribute only replaces one line of code.  Don't inject it in the Dispose() method :)

Comment: -1: I don't think, he meant to put this code into his `Dispose` method, but in all other methods or properties, that require the instance to NOT be disposed. `FileStream.Read` is a classical example ;-)

Comment: @Daniel - you are right of course.  That was frikkin unguessable from the question though, at least to me and the other 4 people that voted for this answer.  "Implementing the IDisposable pattern" in the question title might have something to do with that.  Please don't kick the answerers in the groin for crap questions, editing is probably better.

Comment: I'll self-destruct in 6 seconds.

Comment: @Hans: No need for self-destruction ;-) there are two possibilities that can be resolved: (1) You edit your answer, inform me via a comment and **I will remove my downvote** (2) You delete your answer. --- Both options remove the downvote :-) I only downvoted, because so many people upvoted and the answer in my eyes was just wrong :-)

Comment: Hmm, or I edit the question the way most people read it.  Can't delete, reached the 5-per-day limit.  I think I'll do that so you can remove your downvote and feel better :)

Comment: @Hans: I am sorry, but I fail to understand your last comment. But editing the question to match your answer seems like the wrong way ;-)

Comment: Well, don't let a whiff of humor ruin your day.  Option C, answer both questions.

Comment: @Hans: Hehe, it didn't, and I was sure, you didn't mean it. But sometimes it's hard for me to detect humor in written english :-) Removed downvote.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question, it just tells him to do what he stated he doesn't want to do in his question, and then says you could use AOP, which he already knows, but doesn't give him any pointers about which libraries approaches might be suitable.  I fail to see how this is very helpful.

Comment: @Sam - the queue is already wrapping three city blocks, you'll have to join at the end.  Do you have any specific advice on how to do better than replacing one line of code with one attribute?  That's the part that escapes me.

Comment: @Hans, the attribute can be applied to the whole class can't it?  Or maybe to a base class (I've not used postsharp or other AOP framework so I'm not certain)? and it would then be applied to all methods in that class (and maybe class hierarchy?).  This would ensure that any new methods added would not need to have the code snippet added to then, avoiding the issue of a developer forgetting to add the check, and saving 1 line of code per method in the class, for one attribute on the class itself.

Comment: @Hans - I've edit the question. I hope you find it less crappy and easier to guess what it's about.

Answer (score 1):

[PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) will probably allow you do this, although it appears it is no longer free.

You should be able to add the code on a method boundary aspect I believe, and then it will be added to each method (you probably will want to exclude the Dispose method itself.)

**EDIT** there is still a free [community edition](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/purchase/compare)

Answer (score 1):

Throwing ObjectDisposedException from *all* members after an object is disposed is not always appropriate.  Or even from all members except Dispose.  As an example, it's common to access properties exposed by a WinForms Form after it's been shown modally then disposed:

```
using(MyForm myForm = ...)
{
    myForm.ShowDialog();
}
...
// Access myForm properties that correspond to values of controls in MyForm.
```

Or another example: there's no need to prevent a caller from accessing `FileStream.Name` after the FileStream has been disposed - and in fact the FileStream class does allow this.

Hence I'd just keep a code snippet handy to manually paste into those members which explicitly need this functionality: don't just blindly generate code that might not be appropriate.

One additional thing to note: there are two broad classes of IDisposable classes: those that own IDisposable members, and those that directly own an unmanaged resource.  The first case is by far the most common, especially in your own application code.

In the first case, the check is probably superfluous: it will be sufficient to let the owned IDisposable object throw `ObjectDisposedException` if it needs to.  Members that don't access the owned IDisposable object don't need to throw.

In the second case, you do need to throw `ObjectDisposedException` from any member that might attempt to access the unmanaged resource - but not from any other members.  And often you will wrap access to the unmanaged resource into a small number of private members: these members are probably the only ones that need to throw `ObjectDisposedException`.